# RemoteException when creating file with WebHDFS REST API

Tags: hadoop, webhdfs

I have not been able to create a file using Hadoop's WebHDFS REST API.

Following the docs, I'm doing this.

```
curl -i -X PUT "http://hadoop-primarynamenode:50070/webhdfs/v1/tmp/test1234?op=CREATE&overwrite=false"
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 307 TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 04:10:13 GMT
Date: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 04:10:13 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 04:10:13 GMT
Date: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 04:10:13 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Location: http://hadoop-datanode1:50075/webhdfs/v1/tmp/test1234?op=CREATE&namenoderpcaddress=hadoop-primarynamenode:8020&overwrite=false
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
```

Following the redirect:

```
curl -i -X PUT -T MYFILE "http://hadoop-datanode1:50075/webhdfs/v1/tmp/test1234?op=CREATE&namenoderpcaddress=hadoop-primarynamenode:8020"
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 162
Connection: close

{"RemoteException":{"exception":"IllegalArgumentException","javaClassName":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"Failed to parse \"null\" to Boolean."}}
```

I could not find any leads for that error message. Has anyone experienced this before?

I'm running a Hadoop cluster installed using Ambari.

Comment: Was &overwrite=false excluded purposely ?

Comment: It's the same whether overwrite=false is there or not.

Comment: Filed a bug in HDFS JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-10684

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the second PUT command requires a "createparent" parameter. In fact, both "overwrite" and "createparent" are needed. WebHDFS is not using default values. Definitely a bug...

```
curl -i -X PUT -T MYFILE "http://hadoop-datanode1:50075/webhdfs/v1/tmp/test1234?op=CREATE&namenoderpcaddress=hadoop-primarynamenode:8020&overwrite=false&createparent=false"
```

Comment: I didn't need to add the createparent parameter, I was trying to upload the file with a shorter name, but once I made sure the file name on my system matched the file name I was creating on hadoop everything worked.